# Calculate confidence intervalle with group several parameters

Tags: r, dplyr

This is an example to calculate the confidence intervalle of CV ,calculate by EnvStats package, by bootstrap with slipper package.

```
require(EnvStats) 
require(devtools)
devtools::install_github('jtleek/slipper')
require(slipper)

iris %>%
  slipper_ci(EnvStats::cv(Sepal.Length),B=100, lower=0.025, upper=0.975)
```

Now i need to same calcul using group_by and several variables like this. But it does not work.

```
cv_ic <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length)), slipper_ci_f(EnvStats::cv(vars(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `slipper_ci()` needs to be a data frame, which it doesn't get within `summarise()`. The following seems to work :

```
library(tidyverse)

cv_ic <-
  iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(),
                  ~ slipper_ci(as.data.frame(.x),
                                cv(.x),
                                B = 100,
                                lower = 0.025,
                                upper = 0.975)),
            .groups = "keep"
  )
```

Comment: i don't have across function

Comment: The `across()` function is in package `dplyr`. I edited to load the `tidyverse` (including `dplyr`).

Comment: The across() fuction does not exist in my dpyr version. There are an alternative of across function?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot install the package `slipper`.

I don't think you have to pass the `vars(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length)` to the function `cv`.

A purrr-style function should be fine like

```
cv_ic <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length)), ~slipper_ci_f(EnvStats::cv(.x)))
```

I also recommend you to use the `across` function which aims at replace the `*_at/if`.

```
cv_ic <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(c(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length), ~slipper_ci_f(EnvStats::cv(.x))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for yours propositions but does not work. For example in your first proposition slipper_ci_f should be slipper_ci

Comment: If `slipper_ci` takes a data frame as input, just use the answer by meriops. Upgrade your dplyr > 1.0.0 and you will have the `across` function.